# How would I solve the errors which I am getting when trying to use android project from existing code?

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a android app few months ago. Now, when I am trying to edit it by using Android project from existing code, it's showing some errors, that I don't know how to solve, or what it is. I had created this application on android 2.2 API level 8.

I am having 4 errors which are stated below :

1. The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved.
2. Project 'HisaabKiKitaab' is missing required library: 'C:\sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar'
3. Project 'HisaabKiKitaab' is missing required library: 'C:\sdk\platforms\android-4.2\android.jar'
4. Project 'HisaabKiKitaab' is missing required library: 'C:\sdk\extras\google\admob_ads_sdk\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.3.1.jar'

Please help me to how to solve it.

[image: Missing libraries]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough information in your question regarding the error but try this:

**Right click** on the project, Go to **Build Path** > **Configure Build Path** and see if the SDK and other libraries are there or not. If not, add the required libraries into the project and it should start working. That settings are should would look like following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man ! I have added the screen shot of missing libraries. How would I install it now?

Comment: @scripter : Select the library that's missing, click Edit and then locate that again on your PC (you need to have that on your PC first) :)

Comment: This is the problem, I have changed my pc, so I don't know if I have that libraries in my pc or not. IF I don't have it, what should I do then ?

Comment: @scripter : You need to check if the Android SDK exists at `C:\sdk\` as your libraries are being loaded from there. If it doesn't exist, download the SDK again from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html - and then load the libraries from there again. This would resolve the errors. 
If you have SDK and it lacks the some android version apis like android 8 or so, then download those via android SDK manager. 
(Open SDK Manager via Eclipse > Help > Install new Software).
Thanks.